# Counting frames in a video using OpenCV... (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, video, while-loop

I am using a loop to access all frames of a video file using Python and OpenCV. While accessing each frame, I add the index of the frame in a list.

However I compare the size of the list and the number of frames that I get using the

```
Frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
```

command and the size of the list is constantly one less element than the number of the frames of the video reytned by cap.get...
Any ideas why is this happening ?

Here is the code I use:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2

def faceExtraction(inputFile, extractionRate):

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(inputFile)
fps = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
Frames = cap.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
print 'Frames='+str(Frames)
# if not os.path.exists("registered_face"):
        # os.makedirs("registered_face")

frame_counter = 0

outputFrameIndices=[]
while(cap.isOpened()):


        frame_counter=frame_counter+1
        ret, frame = cap.read()  # read current frame
        outputFrameIndices.append(frame_counter)
        if frame is None:
                break


        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

            # print 'FACE NOT FOUND: frame '+ str(frame_counter)
# When everything done, release the capture

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



print 'number of frames: ' + str(len(outputFrameIndices))

############## Executing Main App ###########
faceExtraction('Video Filename blah blah',5)
```

The output my code produces is:
Frames=930.0
number of frames: 929

whereas it should be
Frames=930.0
number of frames: 930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error... Python starts index counters from zero...